# Convert an ASCII decimal string to an integer

Tags: assembly, mips, spim

I coded getting a string and converting it to `int`. But whatever I put in, the result is just `-1`. If I put in `123` the result is `-1` and also if I put in `-123` result is `-1`. I think the problem is string register, but I don't know where is the problem.

```
.globl main
.data
     input : .space 30
.text   
 main:

   li $v0,8 #get string
   la $a0,input
   li $a1, 30
   syscall

   jal str2int   # call the procedure str2int
   move $a0,$v0   # move the return value into $a0
   li $v0,1      
   syscall       # print the result

   li $v0, 10
   syscall        # Exit the program

# register $v0(return value)                         

str2int:
   # Check for sign
   lb $t0,0($a0)   # load the first byte into $t1
   beq $t0,'-',negint # if sign is -,goto negint
   beq $t0,'+',posint # if sign is +,goto posint
   j convert
negint:   li $t1,1       # set flag $t1 to 1(represents negative)
   add $a0,$a0,1   # goto next ASCII character
   j convert   # goto convert
posint:   li $t1,0       # set flag $t1 to 0(represents positive)
   add $a0,$a0,1   # goto next ASCII character
convert:
   li $s0,0       # sum=0
loop:              
   lb $t0,0($a0)   # load the ASCII character into $t1
   beqz $t0,exitloop   # if the character is null, exit the loop
   blt $t0,'0',fail   # if $t1 is a non-digit character,return -1
   bgt $t0,'9',fail
   sub $t0,$t0,48   # convert ASCII digit to decimal digit
   mul $s0,$s0,10   # multiply the previous sum with 10 and
   add $s0,$s0,$t0   # the converted digit to sum
   add $a0,$a0,1   # goto next ASCII character
   j loop       # goto loop
exitloop:
   beq $t1,0,copy   # if sign is +, goto copy
   neg $s0,$s0   # if the sign is -, take negation of integer
copy:   move $v0,$s0   # store the converted integer into $v0  
   j return
fail:    li $v0,-1
return:   jr $ra       # return $v0 to main
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [SPIM syscall documentation](http://students.cs.tamu.edu/tanzir/csce350/reference/syscalls.html):

> read string has the same semantics as the Unix library routine fgets. It reads up to n - 1 characters into a buffer and terminates the string with a null byte. If there are fewer characters on the current line, it reads through the newline and again null-terminates the string.

Note that there will most likely be a newline character at the end of the input string, immediately before the terminating 0. This will trigger an error in your conversion loop. You should explicitly test for this case in a similar way that you test for the terminator:

```
    lb $t0,0($a0)        # load the ASCII character into $t0
    beq $t0,13,exitloop  # if the character is CR, exit the loop
    beq $t0,10,exitloop  # if the character is LF, exit the loop
    beqz $t0,exitloop    # if the character is NUL, exit the loop
    ...
```

(Note that I checked for both CR and LF as line terminators above, as I don't know what platform you're running on).

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't works.
If I declare the asciiz "123" string on the data, it works but, does not work when I receive the input.

Comment: In that case you need to step through the code in the simulator and see what’s going on.